# Why is my script slowly using more and more memory? Is it because of midori?

Tags: bash, scripting, raspberry-pi, raspbian, browser

I made a script to display various websites on an infinite loop, and noticed that the system is slowly consuming more and more memory.  The script works perfectly otherwise.

From what I was able to gather from the `top` command, I believe it's `midori` (the internet browser) that's consuming all (well, at least a large percentage) of the memory.  My `midori` is configured to open all of the pages within the current tab, so there's only ever one instance of `midori` running and only one tab open, yet it still continues to increase it's memory usage.

```
#Start VNC Server
x11vnc -display :0 -usepw -listen ip_addr &

#Sites to display
SITES=( "a bunch of urls here..." )
#Display Time (In Seconds)
TIME=( 125 35 35 35 35 35 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 )


#Open the browser and enter fullscreen mode
midori http://google.com &
sleep 15
xdotool key F11

#Infinite Loop
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do

#Loop through each site
for ((i=0;i<${#SITES[@]};++i)); do
        #Open the site
        midori ${SITES[i]} &

        #Check to see if the site has a display time set in the TIME variable
        if [ -z ${TIME[i]} ];
        then #If the display time is not set, display for 30 seconds
                sleep 30
        else #Display for the appropriate amount of time
                sleep ${TIME[i]}
        fi
done
done
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit:**
It's worth mentioning that when I say it's 'slowly' using more memory, I mean very slowly; after running the script for ~7 hours the memory consumption went from 35% - 61%.

Comment: Is there possibly a way of instructing a running `midori` instance to open the pages? This looks like you're opening a new web browser for each page. (note: I've never used `midori`)

Comment: @ Kusalananda I couldn't find a way to get midori to do it itself. @Theophrastus, When I open a new site, there's only **one** instance of midori running; it simply replaces the old page with the new one.  There are no new windows, tabs or processes.  As for the ampersand, if I don't include it then the script doesn't go past the browser call until the browser is closed.

Comment: Killing the browser process and reopening it every few hours would reset the memory consumption and solve my issue, but I'd like to avoid doing that if I can.  I just don't understand why the memory usage of a single internet tab slowly increases -- maybe it's caching webpages in memory?

Comment: Maybe it's the browsing history :-)

Comment: @tomas Maybe... I set the browser to delete the browsing history every hour, i'll let you know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @tomas Deleting the history periodically didn't seem to help.

Comment: @user183143 Sorry, it was a joke. But I'm working on it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web browsers are notorious memory pigs and leakers of memory, especially if the pages they're viewing have any javascript.  It's just part of their nature.  Aside from maybe the text-mode browsers like `lynx`, I don't think I've ever seen one that **didn't** leak memory over time.

Do you need the browser to stay on screen after the last tab has been displayed?  If not, then `pkill midori` between the two `done` lines.  If you do, then `pkill midori ; midori  ${SITES[i]} &`.  Or, in the `for` loop: `[ "$i" == "${#SITES[@]}" ] && pkill midori` immediately before running `midori`.  or looping from 0 to $(("${#SITES[@]" - 1)), then killing and starting the final midori after the first `done`.

Or, probably the simplest, just `pkill midori` immediately after the `while` statement (if midori isn't running, no error message is printed,  and nothing happens unless you're running with `set -e`).

If you don't have `pkill` installed (it's in the `procps` package on debian and raspbian), you can capture the PID of the midori process whenever it gets killed and restarted, and kill that specific PID.  e.g.

```
while [ 1 ]; do
  mPID=0

  for ((i=0;i<"${#SITES[@]}";++i)); do
    midori "${SITES[i]}" &
    [ "$mPID" -eq 0 ] && [ -n "$(jobs -n)" ] && mPID=$!
    [ "$mPID" -eq 0 ] && echo "couldn't start midori" && exit 1

    # sleep for for display time if set, otherwise 30 secs.
    [ -n "${TIME[i]}" ] && sleep "${TIME[i]}" || sleep 30
  done
  kill "$mPID"
done
```

That not only gets the PID of any **new** midori process started (`$!` is the PID of the most recent background job), it checks to see if it did get started.  If midori failed to run for any reason, then it exits with an error message.

---

If you weren't running on an rpi, you could add more RAM to your system, if it's at all possible.   It's a fairly cheap way to improve performance and responsiveness of a system, and any "unused" RAM will be used by the kernel to cache your disks.

---

I wrote a script that you might find useful, called `mem-pigs.sh` to total the memory usage for specified programs.  defaults to the browsers I use routinely (because they're the memory hogs).

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# print total RSS memory usage for program(s) with multiple pids

# set default if no args
[ -z "$1" ] && set -- chromium firefox midori

for p in "$@" ; do
  printf "%s:\t%s %s\n" "$p" $( 
    ( printf '1024*(%s)\n' \
        $(awk '
               BEGIN {if (ARGC==1) { print 0 ; exit } };
               /VmRSS:/ {print $2}
              ' \
            $(pgrep "$p" | sed -e 's:^:/proc/:;s:$:/status:') | 
          paste -sd+)
    ) | 
      bc | 
      human-numbers.pl)
done
```

sample output:

```
$ mem-pigs.sh
chromium:   9.81 GiB
firefox:    1.39 GiB
midori: 2.76 GiB
```

`midori` would probably use more if I used it as a general purpose browser, but I use it solely for facebook and nothing else.  chromium and firefox for random browsing on things that interest me.

`chromium` is the real pig.  it's using only 10GB at the moment, but that's because I restarted it a few hours ago because of an upgrade (it was about 14GB before that).  same for `firefox`, it's usually around 4-6GB.  But I leave them both running for weeks or months at a time with a dozen or three tabs per window in 20 or more windows each.  each window being mostly on a particular topic i'm reading about.

I was kind of horrified to see how much chromium in particular was using....then I thought "doubling my RAM to 32GB is only $100". now i don't really care.  I'd have upgraded to 64GB if my motherboard was DDR4 or if 32GB DDR3 DIMMS weren't unreasonably expensive.

`mem-pigs.sh` uses another of scripts, `human-numbers.pl`:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $units = 1024;
my @suffixes=map { $_ ne 'B' && $_ } qw(B KiB MiB GiB TiB PiB EiB ZiB YiB);

if ( (@ARGV) && (($ARGV[0] eq '--si') || ($ARGV[0] eq '-s' )) ) {
  shift;
  $units = 1000;
  @suffixes=map { $_ ne 'B' && $_ } qw(B KB MB GB TB PB EB ZB YB);
};

# Use stdin and/or command-line args as input
# NOTE: command-line args are processed AFTER lines from stdin)
# TODO: option to process args BEFORE STDIN.
my @input = @ARGV;
@ARGV=();

if ( -p STDIN ) {
  while (<>) {
    push @input, $_;
  };
};

my $index=0;

for (@input) {
   my $n = $_ ;
   my $index = 0;

   for (@suffixes) {
     last  if $n < $units ;
     $n = $n / $units;
     $index++
   };

   printf "%.2f %s\n", $n, $suffixes[$index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this.  As we're running this on a Raspberry Pi, upgrading the RAM isn't really an option.  But after reading this I feel like my current solution to just reboot it during off-hours may be the best option.

Comment: there should be no need to reboot, either of the `pkill`-based variants i suggested would be enough.  i'll update my answer with a few more.  the memory leakage is caused by the fact that you have one long-running midori process (the first one that got started).  every time you run midori again, it doesn't start a new process, it just tells the old one to load a different page.  killing `midori` causes all memory used by it to be released.